# Retrieve values from notification using JSON PAYLOAD android

Tags: android, jsonp, xtify

I am in a situation , where my webservice sends me notification which includes

```
{
    "apiKey": "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
    "appKey": "xxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
    "sendAll": true,
    "content": {
        "subject": "Test Lottery",
        "message": "Notification Msg",
        "action": {
            "type": "DEFAULT",
            "data": "url|intent|...",
            "labe": "label"
        },
        "payload": "{'uid':'1','type':'LD'}",
        "sound": "default.caf",
        "badge": "+1"
    }
}
```

On click of the notification which appeared on top , I need to get the `uid` and `type`

I am using Xtify for push notification.....

Comment: `I am having a beginner knowledge in JSON` then you have to extend the knowledge ...

Comment: leave those funny comments ..... if possible help me ...

Comment: seems like it is not possible(to help you) becuase you are too lazy to use http://google.com before asking the question, it is duplicate of many questions here ... please do some research before asking

Comment: selvin please allow other to help ....

Comment: @karthik : its not a way to ask help.......... you are here to help.. if you talk like that no one gonna help you....

Comment: @karthik : be polite... at-least when you are asking for help...

Comment: @Selvin Is right . Such kind of questions are not allowed here as there are so many questions asked like this. You need to put your efforts to find out solutions atleast besides directly getting prepared materials. And its so simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This..

```
String JSON ="YOUR JSON RESULT STRING";
try {
    JSONObject jsonresult = new JSONObject(JSON);

    String apiKey= jsonresult.getString("apiKey");
    String appKey= jsonresult.getString("appKey");
    boolean sendAll= jsonresult.getBoolean("sendAll");

    JSONObject contentObject = jsonresult.getJSONObject("content");
    String subject= jsonresult.getString("subject");
    String message= jsonresult.getString("message");
    String sound= jsonresult.getString("sound");
    String badge= jsonresult.getString("badge");

    JSONObject actionObject = jsonresult.getJSONObject("action");

    String type= jsonresult.getString("type");
    String data= jsonresult.getString("data");
    String labe= jsonresult.getString("labe");

    JSONObject payloadObject = jsonresult.getJSONObject("payload");
    // do your code..

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    //catching exceptions if any...
}
```

Comment: why? why you are answering? it is duplicate, then mark it as duplicate

Comment: i downvoted because i don't like reputation grinding on questions which already has an answer here